# Having a rails model with autosave, should I validate_associated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, autosave

I have a Device model that belongs to a Contact:

```
belongs_to :contact, autosave: true
validates_presence_of :contact
```

I have add the `autosave` and the `validates_presence_of` because the device:

- Needs a valid and persisted contact

Regarding at the [AutosaveAssociation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html), it shouldn't be necessary to add this line:

```
validates_associated :contact
```

Because: `If validations for any of the associations fail, their error messages will be applied to the parent`

But, in this context, I am receiving this results:

```
> device.valid?
> => true
> device.contact.valid?
> => false
```

**Why is device valid if autosave is true for contact and contact is not valid?**

NOTE: I didn't found good documentation about **how autosave with Mongo**. This question is based in Mongo. I found great documentation about autosave with ActiveRecord, but I would like to understand how it really works with mongo.

Answer (score 2):

I've posted a comment here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-4132?focusedCommentId=1033059&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-1033059

The core reason why your validations are not working as you expect is because your schema dictates that the Device is the child and the Contact is the parent. You should inverse this relationship to get the behavior you're expecting.